# Using Remy Sharp twiterlib

Tags: javascript, twitter

So I have come across this excellent twitter library from Remy Sharp. Hoever I am not able to find an real instructions on how to implememt it, I have included the .js file and wish to use it in the following way to produce the 5 most recent updates from a user account.

But I cannot see how I actually output it to html correctly.

```
twitterlib.timeline("xclusivfitness", { page: 1, limit: 5 }, callback);
```

I presume i need to create a function to produce the html, but have hit a wall.

Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

He's documented this library at https://github.com/remy/twitterlib.  That should give you a good start.